# Determine excel columns having some value

Tags: vba, excel

My objective is to determine the columns in sheet having some value. if A column doesn't have value it should be hidden.I have tried it as :

```
Sub HideEmptyCols()
    Dim LastCol As Long, i As Long
    LastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

    For i = 1 To LastCol
        If WorksheetFunction.Count(Columns(i)) = 0 Then
            Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

It works fine if a column doesn't have any value but if a column has value in last row it also hide that column. I am looking for exactly why is this happening and how to achieve the objective?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Sub ColumnHider()
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    nLastRow = r.Rows.Count + r.Row - 1
    nLastColumn = r.Columns.Count + r.Column - 1

    For i = 1 To nLastColumn
        Set rcol = Cells(1, i).EntireColumn
        If wf.CountA(rcol) = 0 Then
            rcol.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

This version will hide the column if all the cells **below the header** are empty:

```
Sub ColumnHider()
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    nLastRow = r.Rows.Count + r.Row - 1
    nLastColumn = r.Columns.Count + r.Column - 1

    For i = 1 To nLastColumn
        Set rcol = Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(Rows.Count, i))
        If wf.CountA(rcol) = 0 Then
            rcol.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: 50% of the question answered but `why is this happening?`

Comment: @mehow  I can not answer that without seeing the OP's worksheet.

Comment: My first column has headers but its working only if top row doesn't have any value.

Comment: Well if the top row has a value, then the column is **not** empty and the column should not be hidden.

Comment: except the header(Column), if column doesn't have value it must be hidden. Hope its more clear.